# Why do url not start android instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I spent hours without success to understand why my Url do not open my Android instant app form Google Play (Open Beta)

With android App link assistant everything seems ok. I can run the app as instant. No problem.
I checked that my .well-known/assetlinks.json is correct and is at the root of my domain. This file is reachable from external domains

I use the instant app url from a mail (I do not write it directly in a browser). But instead of getting the app I land to my webpage.

Thanks for any help

Comment: can you try click this link from another mail client and/or web-client? is it behaves in the same way?

Comment: The link was on Gmail so I very little risk that it would not work.  Anyway I made a webpage with the link. Click on that link does not lead to a better result unfortunately